# Grails and Cloudbees

Tags: grails, cloudbees

I am following this [tutorial](http://developer.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/Grails) on Grails and Cloudbees And it says :

"to use CloudBees databases locally from your application, you first need to add the CloudBees SDK's appserver.jar file to your grails classpath"

Does anyone know what is this `appserver.jar`? Where can I find it?

Comment: Could it be the stax-appserver-core you get after you download their SDK? https://wiki.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/BeesSDK

Comment: Yea, that's what I was going to suggest as well.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as mentioned in the comment - you can get that jar file from the SDK you download.

However, it is perfectly find (and possibly better) to use the mysql driver directly as mentioned.

When running on cloudbees, you can bind your app to a database - so that at runtime the right database is injected - using the bees db:bind SDK command.